# Is there an support in android to know all states of phone call?

Tags: android, call

In TelephonyManager class you can know about only three states:-

1)CALL_STATE_RINGING

2)CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK

3)CALL_STATE_IDLE

I want to know if we can identify the state when called party picks the call.

Answer (score 0):

When the party picks up the call, it comes from `CALL_STATE_RINGING` to `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

1. Ringing-->offhook : User picked up
2. Offhook -->Idle : Call hung up
3. Idle--> Ringing : New Incoming call
4. Ringing-->Idle : Missed Call
5. Idle-->Offhook : New Outgoing call

Comment: But how can we know that outgoing called has been picked?

Comment: That's what I answered. When call state comes from ringing to outhook. So save the previous state and when state changes, just check if it's from ringing to outhook.